# Dart: microtypes

Tags: dart, types

Does Dart have any good patterns or libraries for "microtypes" / "branded types" (that is, a way to distinguish different flavours of more basic types like Strings in the type system). For example, you could have a type for an `EmailAddress` and a different one for a `UserId`, and you couldn't accidentally mix the two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible right now but there are a old issue for this here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2626

It seems this feature are planned to come in the near future if you read the latest comments on that issue.

Comment: I think that issue is chiefly about (interchangable) type aliases (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2626#issuecomment-464638272), which is a somewhat different feature. There is a linked suggestion for doing microtypes (branding) with the linter (https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1264).